# Aes ggplot categorize by color not filling the whole barplot

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, bar-chart, visualization

I have been looking for the solution online but I cant get the suitable one. So here is my data:

```
   tag    Center   n    n_tag  persen
1  lisan  я        103  2142   0.048085901
2  medrus я        11   2588   0.004250386
3  medsos я        28   2778   0.010079194
4  puisi  я        66   2622   0.025171625
```

And this is my code to visualize a barplot, where x = tag, y = persen.

```
ggplot(df_persen, aes(tag, persen, color=Center) + geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.6) + theme_classic()
```

Here is the following result:

[image]

As you can see, the color is only in the outline. I want the color to fill the whole barplot, not only the outline.

I know that we can color the whole barplot using fill in geom_bar like this:

```
ggplot(df_persen, aes(tag, persen)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.6, fill="cyan4") + theme_classic()
```

[image]

And I want the barplot to be looking approximately like that. Yes I understand that my current data has only 1 variable in the column Center, but I will add it more later, so that I can categorize it based on the color based off the variables in Center.

How can I do that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include fill = Center inside the aes() function to specify the fill color based on the "Center" variable

```
df_persen <- data.frame(
      tag = c("lisan", "medrus", "medsos", "puisi"),
      Center = rep("я", 4),
      n = c(103, 11, 28, 66),
      n_tag = c(2142, 2588, 2778, 2622),
      persen = c(0.048085901, 0.004250386, 0.010079194, 0.025171625)
    )
    
    # Load the ggplot2 library
    library(ggplot2)
    
    # Plot the barplot
    ggplot(df_persen, aes(tag, persen, fill = Center)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.6) +
      theme_classic()
```

Comment: Hey it works! Thank you, I have tried that one but turns out there was a typo in my code so it didnt work properly. Again thanks!